# Fractional Linear Transformation of the Image of the Line $y=4-x$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, mobius-transformation

> I am trying to find the image of the line $y=4-x$ under the fractional linear transformation $$w=\frac{8}{z-2-2i}.$$

My method is as follows:

Rearranging yields $$z=\frac{8}{w}+2+2i.$$
Now, \begin{align}
z=x+iy&=\frac{8}{u+iv}+2+2i \\
&=\frac{8+(u+iv)(2+2i)}{u+iv}\times\frac{u-iv}{u-iv} \\
&=\frac{8u+2u^2+2v^2}{u^2+v^2}+i\frac{2u^2-8v+2v^2}{u^2+v^2}
\end{align}
Equating real and imaginary components yields 
$$x=\frac{8u+2u^2+2v^2}{u^2+v^2} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ y=\frac{2u^2-8v+2v^2}{u^2+v^2}.$$
Hence, $$\frac{2u^2-8v+2v^2}{u^2+v^2}=4-\frac{8u+2u^2+2v^2}{u^2+v^2}\implies v=u.$$

Is my method valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct.

Here is a shorter way using the properties of the given mapping:

- Note that your mapping is a so called [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). So, it maps generalized circles (circles and lines) onto generalized circles.
- To find the image of the line $y= 4-x$ which is the same as $z=x + (4-x)i$ you need only the image of $3$ points:

$$x = 0 \Rightarrow z = 4i \mapsto w = -2(1+i)$$
$$x = 4 \Rightarrow z = 4 \mapsto w = 2(1+i)$$
$$\mbox{Finally } z = \infty \mapsto w = \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{8}{z-2-2i} = 0$$
So, the image is the line passing through $-2(1+i), 2(1+i), 0$. Hence, you get
$$\boxed{y = x}$$